# What does the asterisk in C do?

Tags: c

What does the * mean in C? I see it used when declaring a char or FILE variable (`char = *test`) How does that change how a variable behaves?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. To someone, who is just learning C this is a more relevant question compared to "Pointers in C: when to use ...", because the latter implies, that you already know about pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of `*` is called "indirection operator", and `*test` means "get the data from where the pointer `test` points".

`char` is reserved for use as a keyword, so `char = *test` won't compile unless `char` is defined as a macro.

Comment: This type of asterisk is for declaring a pointer, not for dereferencing.

Answer (score 6):

It dereferences a pointer:

```
*ptr = 42; // access the value that ptr points to, and set it to 42
```

or it declares a pointer:

```
int* ptr; // the type of ptr is pointer to int
```

Comment: In the same manner, *p=42; means, that you assign 42 to p, which is wrong if p points to nowhere.

Comment: No, `*p = 42` doesn't assign to `p`, it assigns to `*p` (i.e. the thing that `p` points to). And yes, that's undefined behavior if `p` doesn't point to valid memory.